# How to use Pinia outside a component in js file

Tags: pinia

I am migrating from vue 4.x to pinia, one of my file needs api key from  store.
But I can't make it work even though I follow the [Pinia documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications) .
here is how I use pinia

// Repository.ts

```
import axios from "axios";

import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/auth-store'
const pinia=createPinia();
let authStore = useAuthStore(pinia);
const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5678/res-api';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers:{"Authorization":"Bearer " + authStore.getToken,
"Accept":"application/json"},
  
});
```

Expected result : to get the token from the store.

Console error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useAuthStore' before initialization
    at Repository.ts:6:17
    

Note: this working inside a component
```

Comment: Have you tried to set headers in request interceptors and call `useAuthStore` in the config function?

Answer (score 19):

You can solve this by importing the store inside the interceptors

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/auth-store';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5678/res-api'
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authStore.getToken}`;
    config.headers.Accept = "application/json";
    return config
})

export default axiosClient;
```

This discussion may help you: [Go to GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/687#discussioncomment-1374812)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the pinia you created must go as a parameter to app.use. Not only that, but useAuthStore must be a store defined with defineStore and must not take a parameter. I'll leave a link that can help you, it doesn't create the store but you can browse the side menu to see several examples.

https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample project to demo the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-shamir-sxrlb9.

The main cause here is that you cannot use Pinia's stores before passing it to the Vue's app. So given following code:

```
const pinia = createPinia(); // line 1

createApp(App).use(pinia).mount("#app"); // line 2
```

You cannot trigger any store in between line 1 and 2, but only after line 2.

In your code, likely you trigger an axios call before creating Vue app/add Pinia to Vue app. Please try to delay that axios call to trigger after Vue app's setup is complete.

Comment: Actually you only need to use(pinia), mounting the app is not necessary.

```js
const pinia = createPinia();
createApp(App).use(pinia);
// You may call useAuthStore here 
app.mount("#app");
```